# Integration of exponential functions

Tags: integration

Is the exponential function integrable?

Another question, please:

is there, in general, a difference between integrable and integrable in the Riemann sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the exponential is integrable. Any continuous function is integrable. For your other question, if you are asked if a function is integrable without any qualifications then generally you are being asked about Riemann integration. There are other forms of integration that are out there, such as Lebesgue integration, which show up in measure theory.